# Runtime topic subscription in WSO2 ESB using JMS

Tags: publish-subscribe, wso2, qpid, wso2-esb

I have a topic in the WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 that I want to create subscriptions to at runtime using JMS, to allow pub-sub.

It is documented that the event-broker in 4.6.0 is based on Apache Qpid, however, it doesn't appear to be bundled.  By default, an in-memory event broker is configured.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Eventing

I am using ActiveMQ as my JMS message broker, however, if required, it is possible to change to Qpid.

Has anyone managed to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use apache Qpid as your JMS broker with WSO2 ESB. It has been tested in production enviornments as well. You can follow the same steps as mentioned in the samples which uses ActiveMQ as the JMS broker.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I can use it as the JMS however, there appears to be a distinction between the message broker and event broker components.

I want to be able to register runtime JMS subscriptions against topics, which appears to require Qpid as the event broker.